# Loop through list of dictionaries if certain values to create a new list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am working on a project off codecademy focusing on creating custom iterable classes and having trouble figuring out this section.

I have a list of dictionaries of students, example below:

```
student_roster = [
  {
    "name": "Karina M",
    "age": 8,
    "height": 48,
    "favorite_subject": "Math",
    "favorite_animal": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "name": "Yori K",
    "age": 7,
    "height": 50,
    "favorite_subject": "Art",
    "favorite_animal": "Cat"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Alex C",
    "age": 7,
    "height": 47,
    "favorite_subject": "Science",
    "favorite_animal": "Cow"
   }]
```

What I need to do is iterate through the dictionaries in this list, and if a particular student's "favorite_subject" is either "Math" or "Science", I need to grab their name and add them to a separate list.

I have tried multiple options and but I seem to keep adding EVERYONE to my new list, as the dictionary, rather than just grabbing only the value of their name to add to a list.

The end goal is to have a list:

stem = [Karina M, Alex C, etc]

I have tried a number of attempts, but for example, my most recent attempt. This is within the custom class created:

```
def get_students_with_subject(self): 
    stem = []
    for i in range(len(student_roster)): 
      for key, value in student_roster[i].items(): 
        if student_roster[i][key] == "Math" or "Science": 
          stem.append(student_roster[i])
```

When this runs, however, I am just adding every dictionary in my list to the new, stem list and it's not parsing out the specific values.

I have also appended the stem list with:

```
stem.append(student_roster[i][key])
```

But that then adds all values from all dictionaries to the list and I can't figure out how to add JUST the names of JUST the dictionaries that included "favorite_subject" == "Math" or "Science"

I am still learning so any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets simplify the dictionaries in order to get the important data only:

```
student_roster = [
  {
    "name": "Karina M",
    "favorite_subject": "Math",
  },
  {
    "name": "Yori K",
    "favorite_subject": "Art",
  },
  {
    "name": "Alex C",
    "favorite_subject": "Science",
  }
]
```

Now that we have done that, we can start working on implementing a proper solution. First, go ahead and declare a new list:

```
math_and_science_students = []
```

That is the list where you will be adding the names of all the students that like math or science. Now lets work on the loop:

```
for student in student_roster:
    if student["favorite_subject"] in ["Math", "Science"]:
        math_and_science_students.append(student["name"])
```

The `in` operator in this case will check if the student favorite subject is Math or Science. It essentially is the same as saying:

```
if student["favorite_subject"] == "Math" or student["favorite_subject"] == "Science"
```

just much shorter, cleaner and more dynamic.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was apparently over complicating it and getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
student_roster[i][key] == "Math" or "Science"
```

This will alwayse evaluate `True` because the interpreter does not compare your entry to both "Math" and "Science", but only to "Math" and will then evaluate the expression

```
if "Science"
```

as a standalone thing.

You have to do

```
student_roster[i][key] == "Math" or student_roster[i][key] == "Science"
```

or

```
student_roster[i][key] in ["Math", "Science"]
```

Comment: Thank you for helping explain why I was having an issue with my "Math" or "Science" parameter!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line in Python...

```
student_roster = [
  {
    "name": "Karina M",
    "age": 8,
    "height": 48,
    "favorite_subject": "Math",
    "favorite_animal": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "name": "Yori K",
    "age": 7,
    "height": 50,
    "favorite_subject": "Art",
    "favorite_animal": "Cat"
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Alex C",
    "age": 7,
    "height": 47,
    "favorite_subject": "Science",
    "favorite_animal": "Cow"
   }]

new_list = [student for student in student_roster if (student['favorite_subject'] == 'Math' or student['favorite_subject'] == 'Science')]
```

I'm creating a new list by adding a condition.

Your code will work if you change this line:

```
if student_roster[i][key] == "Math" or "Science":
```

to this:

```
if student_roster[i][key] == "Math" or student_roster[i][key] == "Science":
```

... to explain the one liner:

```
new_list = [<new-item> for <potentially-new-item> in <existing-list> if <condition-needed-to-make-potential-item-the-new-item>]
```

Comment: Thank you! I definitely knew a list comprehension would work, but I was struggling to figure out how to the for loop to operate as I waned in general, so I was writing it out to be easier to follow for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition in a container (`set` is recommended here) and use `in` for the check.

```
stems = [d["name"] for d in student_roster for v in d.values() if v in {"Math", "Science"}]
```